# Why SQL function always returning empty result set?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, xml

Following `function` I have write which accept `xml` and returns `table` as result.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FunctionTest(@ID INT,@XML_Details xml)
RETURNS @RESULT TABLE
(
    Value1 INT,
    Value2 INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tbl_Xml_Result Table
    (
        Value1 INT,
        Value2 INT
    )

    INSERT INTO @RESULT(Value1,Value2)
    SELECT 
        l.v.value('Value2[1]','INT'),
        l.v.value('Value1[1]','INT')
    FROM @XML_Details.nodes('/Listings/listing')l(v)
    RETURN
END
```

And following is the code I using to run against above `function` but it always returning `Empty` result.

```
DECLARE @tbl_Xml_Result Table
(
        Value1 INT,
        Value2 INT
)
INSERT INTO @tbl_xml_Result
values(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6)


DECLARE @xml_Temp xml

SET @xml_Temp = (   SELECT * 
                    FROM @tbl_xml_Result
                    FOR XML PATH('Listing'),ROOT('Listings')
                )

DELETE FROM @tbl_xml_Result
INSERT INTO @tbl_xml_Result(Value1,Value2)
Select 
    T.Value1,
    T.Value2
FROM FunctionTest(1,@xml_Temp) T

select * from @tbl_Xml_Result
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XQuery is case-sensitive, as are things generally when dealing with XML.  Correct your function to have an upper-case `Listing` element and it will work.  I note you also pass in `@ID` but don't use it and have accidentally swapped around your `Value1` and `Value2` columns. You should also always use the `text()` accessor when reading untyped XML for a performance boost, as in my example below.

This worked for me:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FunctionTest(@ID INT,@XML_Details xml)
RETURNS @RESULT TABLE
(
    Value1 INT,
    Value2 INT
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @tbl_Xml_Result Table
    (
        Value1 INT,
        Value2 INT
    )

    INSERT INTO @RESULT(Value1,Value2)
    SELECT 
        l.v.value('(Value1/text())[1]','INT'),
        l.v.value('(Value2/text())[1]','INT')
    FROM @XML_Details.nodes('/Listings/Listing')l(v)

    RETURN
END
GO


DECLARE @tbl_Xml_Result Table
(
        Value1 INT,
        Value2 INT
)
INSERT INTO @tbl_xml_Result
values(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6)


DECLARE @xml_Temp xml

SET @xml_Temp = (   SELECT * 
                    FROM @tbl_xml_Result
                    FOR XML PATH('Listing'),ROOT('Listings')
                )



DELETE FROM @tbl_xml_Result
INSERT INTO @tbl_xml_Result(Value1,Value2)
Select 
    T.Value1,
    T.Value2
FROM FunctionTest(1,@xml_Temp) T

select * from @tbl_Xml_Result
```

My results:

[image: My results]

Just as an aside, your function is simple enough to be an inline table-valued function rather than a multi-line one.  Inline TVFs generally perform better.  Post back if you want to know more about that.

HTH